# Unable to parse xml string using Xdocument and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I would like to parse the below xml using XDocument in Linq.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <Sources>
      <Item>
         <Id>1</Id>
         <Name>John</Name>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Id>2</Id>
         <Name>Max</Name>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Id>3</Id>
         <Name>Ricky</Name>
      </Item>
   </Sources>
</string>
```

My parsing code is :

```
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var xElements = xDoc.Element("Sources")?.Elements("Item");
    if (xElements != null)
        foreach (var source in xElements)
        {
            Console.Write(source);
        }
```

`xElements` is always null. I tried using namespace as well, it did not work. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
string stringXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><Sources><Item><Id>1</Id><Name>John</Name></Item><Item><Id>2</Id><Name>Max</Name></Item><Item><Id>3</Id><Name>Ricky</Name></Item></Sources></string>";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(stringXml);
var items = xDoc.Descendants("{http://tempuri.org/}Sources")?.Descendants("{http://tempuri.org/}Item").ToList();
```

I tested it and it correctly shows that `items` has 3 lements :) Maybe you used namespaces differently (it's enough to inspect `xDoc` objct in object browser and see its namespace).

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the namespace and can directly use `Descendants` method to fetch all `Item` nodes like:

```
XNamespace ns ="http://tempuri.org/";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var xElements = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "Item");

 foreach (var source in xElements)
 {
     Console.Write(source);
 }
```

This prints on Console:

```
<Item xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>John</Name>
</Item><Item xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>Max</Name>
</Item><Item xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Name>Ricky</Name>
</Item>
```

See the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qo6dj6)